# php String manipulation

Tags: php, json

**Problem**

I want to extract all the values from following string and store it in the variables. Any help will be aprreciated

**Code**

```
{"status":0,"body":{"updatetime":1371670079,"more":112,"measuregrps":[{"grpid":126426711,"attrib":2,"date":1371654000,"category":1,"measures":[{"value":8159,"type":1,"unit":-2},{"value":4530,"type":5,"unit":-2},{"value":44478,"type":6,"unit":-3},{"value":3629,"type":8,"unit":-2}]}]}}
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: json_decode() might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Did you try out [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

It will return a nested array if the second parameter is set to `true` and nested objects if you omit the second parameter.

```
php> json_decode('{"status":0,"body":{"updatetime":1371670079,"more":112,"measuregrps":[{"grpid":126426711,"attrib":2,"date":1371654000,"category":1,"measures":[{"value":8159,"type":1,"unit":-2},{"value":4530,"type":5,"unit":-2},{"value":44478,"type":6,"unit":-3},{"value":3629,"type":8,"unit":-2}]}]}}', true);
array (
  'status' => 0,
  'body' => 
  array (
    'updatetime' => 1371670079,
    'more' => 112,
    'measuregrps' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'grpid' => 126426711,
        'attrib' => 2,
        'date' => 1371654000,
        'category' => 1,
        'measures' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'value' => 8159,
            'type' => 1,
            'unit' => -2,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'value' => 4530,
            'type' => 5,
            'unit' => -2,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'value' => 44478,
            'type' => 6,
            'unit' => -3,
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'value' => 3629,
            'type' => 8,
            'unit' => -2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```